# Date is missing in CRU data

Tags: raster, r, netcdf, climate, rasterbrick

I used the following code to extract "Climate research Unit" climate data. However extracted data showing "Date       : NaN, NaN (min, max)".

```
pre <- brick("cru_ts4.06.1901.2021.pre.dat.nc", varname="pre")

> pre
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 360, 720, 259200, 1452  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : cru_ts4.06.1901.2021.pre.dat.nc 
names      : X1901.01.16, X1901.02.15, X1901.03.16, X1901.04.16, X1901.05.16, X1901.06.16, X1901.07.16, X1901.08.16, X1901.09.16, X1901.10.16, X1901.11.16, X1901.12.16, X1902.01.16, X1902.02.15, X1902.03.16, ... 
Date       : NaN, NaN (min, max)
varname    : pre *
```

Why is this showing like this and how can I fix it?

Comment: What version of the `raster` package are you using? Are you getting your data from https://crudata.uea.ac.uk/cru/data/hrg/cru_ts_4.06/cruts.2205201912.v4.06/pre/  because its useful to have the link so we can try this. You should also include `library(raster)` in your question too.

Comment: This works okay for me using raster version(`packageVersion("raster")`) 3.5.15 in R 4.1.1 on Linux.

Comment: my version is > packageVersion("raster")
[1] ‘3.6.14’